# How to make ringtones louder so that I can hear it in a loud environment?

Tags: ringtone

It seems that the only ringtone I was able to hear was the one in my old Nokia phone, 10 years ago. Nowadays, in the era of smartphones, no matter which ringtone I chose, I have problems hearing it when I am out in a loud environment. And yes, regardless of the fact that the audio level is set to max.

How can I make my ringtones louder on my phone so that I can hear them easily on a noisy environment? Maybe there is a setting to make ringtones high-pitched?

Comment: Have you considered vibrate mode ?

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: Galaxy s Ii is the phone. Of course I tried vibration but it's the same.

Comment: What about letting the screen flash(or camera light flash)?

Answer (score 4):

Though the is a little bit vague in nature, seems a very useful question for a larger community. You can use [high pitched ringtones](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+high+pitched+ringtones) which are very common around the internet.

Also I came across [this post at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=27996410&postcount=1) which seems quite useful for you. (did not test them myself  though. even if me or anybody did, the level you require might be different.)

In the Google Play Market, there are apps like [Super Loud Ringtones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clear.loud&hl=en), [Loud Ringtones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rayg.loudringtones&hl=en), [LOUD Ringtones](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrj.loudringtones&hl=en)

You must consider the [suggestion](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50450/recommend-loud-ringtone-i-can-hear-in-loud-environment#comment67872_50450) made by Shywim as well.